# Nonparametric Methods for Two Sample Quantile Test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, quantiles, nonparametric-density

## Background

I want to compare two populations' quantile, e.g. 99.99% quantile, 95% quantile. So I am searching for methods for two sample quantile testing. Unfortunately, the population does not obey norm distribution, which means some parametric methods is unsuitable.

For example:

> Control group data: [1,2,3,5,9]
> Treatment group data: [1,2,4,7,8,9,20]
> I want to compare the 50% quantile difference between these 2 samples. I need point estimate/CI/p-value for `quantile difference`

## Question

Is there any nonparametric methods to compare two samples' quantile? I want to get point estimate, CI and p-value.

Methods I collected are sign test, Brown Moods' Test(chi-square test) and bootstrap. The former 2 methods can not give CI for quantile difference and Bootstrap has large computational cost. Is there any other method?

Comment: Do you mean that you have two groups and want to compare them on both the $99.99$th and $95$th percentiles?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: What assumptions are you willing to make about the distributions?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe no assumptions on distributions. The shape of distribution may change. If I can assume shape of distribution unchange, then U test and Hodges Lehmann estimator may be useful

Comment: Use order statistics.  This reduces the problem to comparing two Binomial distributions and a good test can be developed by comparing likelihood ratios.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give more infomation, like methods' name or precedure? It seems like Brown Moods' Test

Comment: What is the scenario which leads to a usable value for the 99.99th percentile but does not calculate it exactly?